# Syntax for wfs-t request

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs-t

I am in need of the correct syntax for performing transaction on WFS layer using OpenLayers. I have gone through many examples on the OpenLayers site and other examples, but can't figure out how to use the necessary and optional options like geometryname, schema etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this [example](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html). I am using same codes for my layers and they are working fine. But   be specific in giving SRID.