# edit openlayers feature attribute and save in geoserver

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, getfeatureinfo

I have a layer in geoserver and I want to get this layer with WMS in OpenLayers.

```
population = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("population",
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/world/wms", 
    {'layers': 'population', transparent: true, format: 'image/png'},
    {isBaseLayer: false}
);
```

I get the property of feature with `OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo`.

```
featureInfo = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
    queryVisible: true,
    layers: [population],
    output: 'features',
    infoFormat : 'application/vnd.ogc.gml',
    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GML,
    eventListeners: {
        getfeatureinfo: showInfo
    }
});
```

I want to edit the property of some features.

How can i do?

Comment: Hi Morteza! You have posted 5 questions in the previous 2 days about WFS and WFS editing. While there is no limit on the number of questions that you can post, I'll suggest that you do some research before posting new questions for every small issue. That way you'll get a better response, and better quality answers.

Comment: Hi. Yes sir, in before 4 post I do some research but in this question I didn't. so sorry for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can't edit the content of a WMS using OpenLayers.  A WMS provides access to a data set (could be vector or raster data) as an image (through the GetMap request), and provides access to attribute properties for an image coordinate (through the GetFeatureInfo request).  This information is **read-only**.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @nmtoken, WMS is read-only and can't edit the property of features. To edit you need WFS-T (Web Feature Service with Transaction) and Transaction must be enabled for that layer in GeoServer. Refer to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25712/syntax-of-wfs-request-in-openlayers) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/syntax-for-wfs-t-request) question for the syntax. [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32243/adding-non-spatial-attributes-using-geoserver) for adding nonspatial attributes.